# Pre-rendering with Rehydration (PRH)

Tags: reactjs, pre-rendering

I'm working on a project, which has two applications, one is an admin portal where users can customize and create their profile and other one is an application which will preview the profile user creates.

All good with the admin portal, which is developed with CRA - React App. Earlier I was planning creating profile app also with React. Anyhow considering SEO and performance I'm thinking about pre-rendering the profile whenever user changes data.

This will improve the performance by considerable margin and SEO as well. SSR is another good solution, however when there are thousands/millinos of users view single profile, there will be a huge demand for server performance. So that I'm planning to work on a POC, which will create static profile with partial cliend side js functionalities for each user and store it somewhere and serve it through CDN.

I want to know two things here -

1. To implement this, I'm having lack of knowledge in terms of available solutions. Solutions for storage, cdn.
2. How can we render static pages during the data changes.

Answer (score 1):

> To implement this, I'm having lack of knowledge in terms of available
> solutions. Solutions for storage, cdn.

Check [Cloudflare CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn/). But there are many other proveriders.

> How can we render static pages during the data changes.

If you are using pre-rendering, You can rebuild the page assets after a profile page is updated and redeploy them.

If you are using SSR then the server load will be high but no need to redeploy (as the page is rendered at runtime from the origin server always).

I would recommend you use [Next.JS support for server rendering and pre-rending](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching) instead of implementing them on your own.